# Filtering for Words

Tags: javascript

I need to filter out certain words and only count those.

For example: I want to find counts of words like `and` or `immigration.`

Currently I am calling a function that is used by a click of the button, going into a table.

```
function countWords() {
  var text = document.querySelector('textarea').value
  var div = document.getElementById('output')

  if (text !== '') {

    div.innerHTML = ''

    var dictionary = {}

    text.replace(/\S+/g, function(word) {
      word = word.split('.')[0]
      word = word.split(',')[0]
      word = word.toLowerCase()
      if (dictionary[word] == undefined) {
        dictionary[word] = 1
      } else {
        dictionary[word]++
      }
    })

    var message = '<table data-theme="zebra dark"><thead><tr><th>Word<th>Count</thead></tr><tbody>'

    for (word in dictionary) {
      message += '<tr><td>' + word + '<td>' + dictionary[word] + '</tr>'
    }

    message += '</tbody></table>'

    div.innerHTML = message

    $('table').DataTable({
      "order": [
        [1, 'desc']
      ]
    })

  } else {

    notification('Please enter at least one word', 'error', 5)

  }

}

document.querySelector('[type=button]').addEventListener('click', countWords)
```

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: To only show the counts for specific words in the table.

Comment: This `word = word.split('.')[0]; word = word.split(',')[0]` will exclude quite a lot of words.

Comment: Can you give us a short example of what you want to achieve?